# Combining joins with other joins or regular queries

Tags: join, solr, lucene

I'd like to combine Solr join queries with regular queries.  As an example, suppose I want to find all stores in Jyväskylä (Finland) selling guide books.  If documents for stores have the fields `city` and `productIds` and documents for products have the fields `productType` and `productId` in my index, I'd expect something like this to work:

```
{!join from=productIds to=productId}productType:"guide book" city:Jyväskylä
```

However, join queries are a particular kind of [LocalParams](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/LocalParams) and those are effective for the entire query.  Therefore, this query would select documents that have `productType=guide book` and `city=Jyväskylä`, which doesn't make any sense.

Worse, suppose I want to look for stores that carry guide books and are located in cities with a population over 1000 people.  I'd need two joins for that (to select products and cities).

Of course, I can split this into a query (`q`) and a filter query (`fq`), but that limits me to two kinds of queries (so, either one regular query and one join query or two joins), and more importantly abuses the concept of queries and filter queries.

My question therefore: how can I combine regular and join queries and how can I have multiple join queries?

Answer (score 0):

I think I've got it: there can be more than one filter query and each can have its own `join` clause.  Solr's admin interface won't let you enter more than one query in the `fq` field, but it's possible through the "Raw Query Parameters" field.

I'm not sure how efficient this is, though.